# Where online compares phonemes across multiple languages, and exhibits the common and distinct ones?

Tags: cross-linguistic

[This answer](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/7227/5306) refers to http://web.phonetik.uni-frankfurt.de/upsid_compare.html.

1. Anyone know why it omits English?

[image]
2. Are there websites that can compare more than 3 languages concurrently?

Answer (score 2):

No website reports common or non-shared segments of arbitrary multiple languages, relative to some database. You can get certain multi-language comparisons from the Frankfurt interface by including a Language Class entry, but you couldn't select e.g. just 3 Chadic languages. You also can't get non-shared segments. For that you would have to do the computations yourself on the UPSID database. There are numerous discussed interfaces in journal articles or former / broken interfaces: the Frankfurt one seems to be the only functioning interface.

The omission of English is a consequence of "the quota rule". To quote from Maddieson's book

> The languages included in UPSID have been chosen to approximate a
>   properly constructed quota sample on a genetic basis of the world's
>   extant languages. The quota rule is that only one language may be
>   included from each small family grouping, for example, among the
>   Germanic languages, one is included from West Germanic and one from
>   North Germanic (East Germanic, being extinct and insufficiently
>   documented for a reliable phonological analysis to be made, is not
>   included).

German was selected, therefore English was not selected. There is no discussion of why specific languages were selected.